# Dynamically Update aframe Videosphere based on screen size

Tags: jquery, aframe

I am having trouble updating the video sphere content based on device size. I am currently doing the code below.

Looking at the code in the dev tools it looks like everything gets updated with the right src files but the a-videosphere doesn't seem to update or reload with the new video source.

I have tried having two different video assets within aframe but it just eats the bandwidth and makes loading way to slow.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<head> 
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>    
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- SCRIPT TO CHANGE VIDEO BASED ON SCREEN SIZE -->
<script>
$(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 769) {
$("#v1").attr("src", "img/Mobile.mp4");}
else if ($(window).width() > 768){
$("#v1").attr("src", "img/Full.mp4");}
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">

<a-assets>
    <video id="video" loop crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline>
         <source id="v1" src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</a-assets>

 <a-videosphere id="videosphere" src="#video" rotation="0 -95 0"></a-videosphere>

 <a-entity id="camera" camera="fov: 75" look-controls></a-entity>

</a-scene>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assets are for preloading/cache. Any change must be done in the entity and not in the assets.

```
$("#videosphere").attr("src", "img/Mobile.mp4");}
```

Comment: Thanks Antony, I actually got this working in this exact way but totally forgot I posted this: appreciate coming back with the answer though :)

Comment: Hi Calum, I was looking for a solution to this problem and came across this question. I posted the answer as soon as I found the solution. This is my first answer on stack overflow. Can you make it the accepted answer as people looking for a solution can confirm to this answer. Thank you.